# How do i find which user has visited which page?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm sending the user id from our app to GA.
I need to see which users (seeing their actual ids) are visiting a specific page.
How do i view that from the analytics dashboard?

Comment: In which parameter you are sending the user id?

Comment: Analytics.set('&uid', _this.id);

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/